# Ionic build failed without specific error

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, amazon-ec2, eslint, react-scripts

After cloning my Ionic React project to my server, I ran `npm install` and all dependencies were installed as expected.

But when I tried to build my app running `sudo ionic build --verbose`, it tooks much more time than usual and ended like this :

```
  eslint:lint-result-cache Persisting cached results: /var/www/html/ms-users-front/node_modules/.cache/.eslintcache +0ms
  eslint:cli-engine Linting complete in: 4827ms +48ms


//It stay here for at least 10min before to failed while it tooks 1min in my local machine.


The build failed because the process exited too early. This probably means the system ran out of memory or someone called `kill -9` on the process.
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess react-scripts.

        react-scripts build exited with exit code 1.

        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
  ionic:utils-process onBeforeExit handler: 'process.exit' received +0ms
  ionic:utils-process onBeforeExit handler: running 1 functions +1ms
  ionic:utils-process processExit: exiting (exit code: 1) +44ms
```

My server is an ec2 instance with httpd installed and everything was working great before I tried to build a new version yesterday.

With exactly the same process, the app is building perfectly on my local machine...

I tried `npm update`, delete eslint cache, and build but without success.

I tried to downgrade Typescript to 4.1 because I had a warning saying that Typescript should be >4.5 and it was 4.7. But after some tests on local, it looks like this has no incidence on the build process.

I'm totally stuck and I absolutly don't know what to try.

Comment: having to use "sudo" seems wrong.

Comment: It ended exactly with the same error without "sudo".

Comment: are you sure you haven't run out of memory as suggested in the error? check both hard drive memory and RAM.

Comment: @AmirAliSaghaei, I don't think I ran out of memory. The build was working perfectly the day before. Also, I don't find anything suspicious in my server's logs.